# Image will not fill div

Tags: html, css, image

CSS/HTML problem.

This is crazy - I can only assume that I am an idiot. I cannot make my image fill the div it is in. There is consistently 5px "padding" beneath the image.

Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>

<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /></head>

<body>
<div class="row">
<img src="pic2.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body, .row, img {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
}

.row {
width: 80%;
background-color: orange;
}

img{
width: 50%;
}
```

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qyk8.jpg

As you can see, the (stupid) blue and red image does not fill the orange div. There is a consistent 5px of orange showing beneath the image. This isn't affected by changes to the % widths of the div or the image, or by resizing the window.

I can fix this with "margin: -5px;", but I want to know why it is happening (especially if under different circumstances the amount is more or less than 5px).

Thanks for your help (and sorry again if this is a ridiculous error on my part).

Comment: Here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/aDtUm/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add a [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value (other than the default `baseline`) to your image like: `top`, `middle`...

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Example:

```css
/* QuickReset */ *, ::after, ::before { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.row {
  background-color: orange;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;    /* or top, bottom, ...  */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69cfcc1895204718647d030c5e887cbe?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG" />
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could make your parent `display` set to: `flex`, `inline-flex`, or `grid` - if that fits your needs

```css
/* QuickReset */ *, ::after, ::before { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.row {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/69cfcc1895204718647d030c5e887cbe?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG" />
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a 'breach' with the page's natural floating for inline images (non floated) they start to respect the element spaces provided for typography like font-size, line height and other. You can easily test that (in the non-working demo): just add body{font-size:50px;} and you'll see how the margined-space will increase. By setting a vertical alignment to images we make sure to provide a placement different from the browser's default.

Comment: Right, I get it. I never would have worked that out. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @jkdume Thanks to you! [Here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/vertical-align/) is an interesting article

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by setting `display` of `img` to `block`:

```
display: block;
```